# PyMC3 & Theano - Theano code that works stop working after pymc3 import

Tags: python, theano, pymc3

Some simple theano code that works perfectly, stop working when I import pymc3

Here some snipets in order to reproduce the error:

```
#Initial Theano Code (this works)    
import theano.tensor as tsr

x = tsr.dscalar('x')
y = tsr.dscalar('y')
z = x + y

#Snippet 1
import pymc3 as pm
import theano.tensor as tsr

x = tsr.dscalar('x')
y = tsr.dscalar('y')
z = x + y

#Snippet 2
import theano.tensor as tsr
import pymc3 as pm

x = tsr.dscalar('x')
y = tsr.dscalar('y')
z = x + y

#Snippet 3
import pymc3 as pm

x = pm.theano.tensor.dscalar('x')
y = pm.theano.tensor.dscalar('y')
z = x + y
```

And I get the following error for each of the previous snippets:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/tom/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/gof/op.py in __call__(self, *inputs, **kwargs)
    516                 try:
--> 517                     storage_map[ins] = [self._get_test_value(ins)]
    518                     compute_map[ins] = [True]

/Users/tom/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/gof/op.py in _get_test_value(cls, v)
    478 
--> 479         raise AttributeError('%s has no test value' % v)
    480 

AttributeError: x has no test value

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-ef8582b040f8> in <module>()
      3 x = pm.theano.tensor.dscalar('x')
      4 y = pm.theano.tensor.dscalar('y')
----> 5 z = x + y

/Users/tom/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/tensor/var.py in __add__(self, other)
    126     def __add__(self, other):
    127         try:
--> 128             return theano.tensor.basic.add(self, other)
    129         # We should catch the minimum number of exception here.
    130         # Otherwise this will convert error when Theano flags

/Users/tom/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/gof/op.py in __call__(self, *inputs, **kwargs)
    523                         run_perform = False
    524                     elif config.compute_test_value == 'raise':
--> 525                         raise ValueError('Cannot compute test value: input %i (%s) of Op %s missing default value' % (i, ins, node))
    526                     elif config.compute_test_value == 'ignore':
    527                         # silently skip test

ValueError: Cannot compute test value: input 0 (x) of Op Elemwise{add,no_inplace}(x, y) missing default value
```

Any Ideas ? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this is related to `pymc3` setting `theano.config.compute_test_value = 'raise'`: https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/master/pymc3/model.py#L395

You can explicitly set `theano.config.compute_test_value` back to `'ignore'` to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 2):

Solution proposed [here](https://github.com/snake-charmer-devs/snake-charmer/issues/18) lasts a bit longer than setting the flag. In your shell type:

```
theano-cache purge
```