# How to resolve this ValueError in theano?

Tags: theano, pymc3

I have define a function say funA(x) in my python script. This function runs a neural network based on theano. If I call it one time the code runs well. However, if I try to call it several times with different inputs in the loop, for example:
for i in range(4):
    funA(x[i]) 
when i=0, the code runs well, but when it runs to i=1, the code raise an error:
ValueError: Cannot compute test value: input 0 (x) of Op dot(x, W) missing default value.

I have installed pymc3 and try to set theano.config.compute_test_value back to 'ignore' as in the following link, but failed
[PyMC3 & Theano - Theano code that works stop working after pymc3 import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30236070/pymc3-theano-theano-code-that-works-stop-working-after-pymc3-import)

Another link as in below says, I can try to remove the .theano directory, but I am using windows version of theano, where can I find the .theano directory?
https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/1439

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Good news: The next release of pymc3 will no longer change any theano settings on its own, so that source of bugs will hopefully be a thing of the past.

To clean your theano cache, you can use

`theano-cache purge`

Comment: Great to hear, @aseyboldt, but just wondering if this has been patched in the master branch of PyMC3 already?